# fetch backbone model inside a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, promise

```
    this.shipperModel = new shipperModel();
    this.collection = new packetListCollection(this.options.packetData);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.render);
    this.finalArry = [];
    self.collection.each(function (modelData) {
        self.shipperModel.fetch({
            data: {
                facility_id: modelData.facility_id ? modelData.facility_id : 0
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.records);
            self.finalArry.push(response.records);
        })

    });
    console.log(self.finalArry);
```

my array always comes as blank even though there is data in the response how do i make sure the result gets display only after all the above fetches are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better to completely refetch the whole collection instead of refetching each model?

Anyway, back to the original question, what you are looking for is javascript promises. I think it could be a bit confusing if i'm going to explain it in a comment. Maybe you could take a look at https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ or just google javascript promises and i'm sure you'll find something.

Maybe this is what you're looking for(untested):

```
var requests = [],
  self = this;
this.finalArry = [];

self.collection.each(function (modelData) {
  // Push all requests wrapped in a function into an array
  requests.push(function () {
    return self.model.fetch({
      data: {
        facility_id: modelData.facility_id ? modelData.facility_id : 0
      }
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.records);
      self.finalArry.push(response.records);
    });
  });
});

// Run all requests and map the return value(a promise)
requests = _.map(requests, function (req) {
  return req();
});

// When all requests are done, log
$.when.apply($, requests).then(function (response) {
    console.log(self.finalArry);
});
```

At least i wouldn't recommend using `async: false`, it contributes to a bad user experience.

Comment: the model i am fetching is not the same type as that of the collection sorry my naming is screwed up have updated

Comment: Alright, i'll be back in a sec with some example code!

Comment: @vini: I added some example code now. I don't think `async: false` is a great idea. Maybe you could do something like i did in the example code. A general readup on promises wouldn't hurt because it's really good to know!

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're logging the array outside of your `then()` closure.

```
this.finalArry = [];
self.collection.each(function (modelData) {
  self.model.fetch({
    data: {
      facility_id: modelData.facility_id ? modelData.facility_id : 0
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.records);
    self.finalArry.push(response.records);
    console.log(self.finalArry);
  });
});
```

`fetch()` is an async method, so your original `console.log()` fires before any of the network calls succeed.

Oscar Linde's answer is notable — this is probably not the way you want to do initial data hydration.